# ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - ORA-02291: integrity constraint (PERFMGMT.ZAUTOMATION_PHASE_FK1) violated - parent key not found

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, triggers

i have two tables. In the first one I have a trigger which creates the primary key for the table

```
create or replace TRIGGER zutomation_num_trigger
before INSERT ON zautomation
FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN (new.automation_num IS NULL)
BEGIN
  SELECT zutomation_seq.NEXTVAL  INTO   :new.zAutomationid  FROM   dual;
  :new.automation_num := 'AUT'||LPAD(:new.zAutomationid,9,'0');
END;
```

The second table reference it nad when I am using hibernate to build them I get the error

```
Hibernate: insert into ZAUTOMATION (automation_num, description, region, requested, sector, title, zautomationid) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into ZAUTOMATION_PHASE (automationid, PHASE_NUM, ZPHASEID) values (?, ?, ?)
21:17:52.343 [http-nio-8080-exec-94] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - ORA-02291: integrity constraint (PERFMGMT.ZAUTOMATION_PHASE_FK1) violated - parent key not found



package com.citi.clg.originations.strategic.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "ZAUTOMATION")
//@SequenceGenerator(name="inputAutomationNumSequence",sequenceName="ZUTOMATION_SEQ",allocationSize=1)
public class AutomationEntity implements Serializable{
    

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3657415674729533973L;
    
    @Id 
    @Column(name="zautomationid") 
//  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="inputAutomationNumSequence")
    private long zautomationid;
    
    
    public void setZautomationid(long zautomationid) {
        this.zautomationid = zautomationid;
    }


    public void setAutomationNum(String automationNum) {
        this.automationNum = automationNum;
    }

    @Column(name="automation_num") 
//  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="inputAutomationNumSequence")
    private String automationNum;
     
    
    public long getZautomationid() {
        return zautomationid;
    }


    public String getAutomationNum() {
        return automationNum;
    }

    /*
     * public void setAutomationNum(String automationNum) { this.automationNum =
     * automationNum; }
     */

    
    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;
    
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
    
    @Column(name = "requested")
    private String requested;
    
    @Column(name = "sector")
    private String sector;
    
    @Column(name = "region")
    private String region;
    

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getRequested() {
        return requested;
    }

    public void setRequested(String requested) {
        this.requested = requested;
    }

    public String getSector() {
        return sector;
    }

    public void setSector(String sector) {
        this.sector = sector;
    }

    public String getRegion() {
        return region;
    }

    public void setRegion(String region) {
        this.region = region;
    }
    
    
    
    
      @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
      
      @JoinColumn(name="automationid")
      private Set<AutomationPhaseEntity> resources;
     


    
      public Set<AutomationPhaseEntity> getResources() { return resources; }
      
      public void setResources(Set<AutomationPhaseEntity> resources) {
      this.resources = resources; }
     
    
    
    
    
    

}






package com.citi.clg.originations.strategic.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "ZAUTOMATION_PHASE")
@SequenceGenerator(name="inputAutomationPHASESequence",sequenceName="ZUTOMATION_PHASE_SEQ",allocationSize=1)
public class AutomationPhaseEntity implements Serializable {
    
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ZPHASEID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="inputAutomationPHASESequence")
    private long phaseID;
    public void setPhaseID( long phaseID) {
        this.phaseID=phaseID;
    }

    public long getPhaseID() {
        return phaseID;
    }

    
    
    @Column(name = "automationid")
    private long automationID;
    
    
    
    public long getAutomationID() {
        return automationID;
    }



    /*
     * public void setAutomationID(long automationID) { this.automationID =
     * automationID; }
     */


    @Column(name = "PHASE_NUM")
    String phaseNum;
    


    public String getPhaseNum() {
        return phaseNum;
    }



    public void setPhaseNum(String phaseNum) {
        this.phaseNum = phaseNum;
    }





    

}
```

Can anyone tell me how I can use the id created in the parent table in the child table from the trigger and get the relationship working . SO taht the data is saved in both the tables?

Comment: Are the Hibernate commands executed from the same database session? Either both transactions need to happen in the same database login session, or you will have to commit the changes to the parent table before the child table can see the new keys.

Comment: Yes they are executed in the same database session

Answer (score 1):

I think you went wrong in Mapping Parent's PK to Child's FK in One To Many Relationship.

**Your parent class (AutomationEntity) must be like this: (Delete @JoinColumn from parent class and put it in child class where FK is defined.)**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="automationEntity",targetEntity=PolicyType.class,fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<AutomationPhaseEntity> resources;
```

**Your child class (AutomationPhaseEntity ) must be like this:**

```
@Column(name="automation_entity_id")
private int automationEntityId; // FK that references to automationEntity PK

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER )
@JoinColumn(name = "automation_entity_id", insertable=false, updatable=false);
private AutomationEntity automationEntity;
```

It will work but anyway if you want to get PK from parent and inject it to child FK with sql queries, you can use sql procedures but in this case the procedure should run via CallableStatement of jdbc connection but I think you don't need it because you use hibernate. you shoud just correct your entities as mentioned above.